# how do I add the JSON at the end of the URL to pass to the function

Tags: json, url

This is the function in the cloud as a function:

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request that can provide a "message" field in the body.
 *
 * @param {!Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {!Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld(req, res) {
  // Example input: {"message": "Hello!"}
  if (req.body.message === undefined) {
    // This is an error case, as "message" is required.
        res.status(400).send('No message defined!');
  } else {
    // Everything is okay.
        console.log(req.body.message);
        res.status(200).send('Success: ' + req.body.message);
  }
};
```

How do I add the JSON to the end of the URL to pass the message to the function...
The URL for the function is 
https://us-central1-internal-156105.cloudfunctions.net/myapp

Comment: You should explain a little bit more what you are trying to do, If you want the code to returns you the message you are sending, you are supose to send it in the body of the message. This can be done via [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html). Depending on what language you are using there is a lot of ways you can acheive the same result. Check out [AJAX request](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), it's one of the most common one.

Comment: I thought there might be a way to send the message through a browser on the end of the URL something like https://us-central1-internal-156105.cloudfunctions.net/myapp?JSON=[{"message":"Hello World"}]... I am obviously new to this ...please excuse my lack of protocol and knowledge

Comment: Are you familiar with the syntax of a URL? If not, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL provides an overview of what's possible with URLs, which by the way, is basically incompatible with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

use the"end"

```
res.end(req.body.message)
```